# How to register filterChainProxy in CherryPy?

Tags: python, spring, cherrypy

I recently read 'Spring Python 1.1' by Greg L. Turnquist. to learn spring framework on python.
While learning, I tried a few examples introduced in the book and I bumped into a trouble on chapter 8, "Case Study I - Intergrating Spring Python with your Web Application."

And, I get this error below. I don't have a clue even on google..
500 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy_cprequest.py", line 633, in respond self.namespaces(self.config) File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\reprconf.py", line 115, in **call** exit(None, None, None) File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy_cptools.py", line 446, in **exit** tool = getattr(self, name) AttributeError: 'Toolbox' object has no attribute 'filterChainProxy' 
Powered by CherryPy 3.2.4
I figured out that CherryPy doesn't have the attribute 'filterChainProxy' in cherrypy.tools. However, the example code in main2.py below tries to use "tools.filterChainProxy.on" and that's the reason as far as i know.

I cannot find any solution for this issue on google. Why in the first place the author made this code using tools.filterChainProxy? Was it supported back then, and now it's deprecated? Or, why else? I looked up in the documentation page of cherrypy and still no clue.

Please help me with the code below (I put the related parts in **BOLD**):

```
import cherrypy
import os
from springpython.context import ApplicationContext
from springpython.security.context import *

from ctx2 import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': 8009})

ctx = ApplicationContext(SpringBankAppContext())

SecurityContextHolder.setStrategy(SecurityContextH older.MODE_GLOBAL)
SecurityContextHolder.getContext()

conf = {"/": {"tools.sessions.on":True,
**"tools.filterChainProxy.on":True}**}

cherrypy.tree.mount(
ctx.get_object("view"),
'/',
config=conf)

cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

```
from springpython.config import PythonConfig, Object
from springpython.security.providers import *
from springpython.security.providers.dao import *
from springpython.security.userdetails import *
from springpython.security.vote import *
from springpython.security.web import *
from springpython.security.cherrypy3 import *

from app2 import *

class SpringBankAppContext(PythonConfig):
def __init__(self):
PythonConfig.__init__(self)

@Object
def view(self):
view = SpringBankView()
view.auth_provider = self.auth_provider()
view.filter = self.auth_processing_filter()
view.http_context_filter = self.httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter()
return view

@Object
def **filterChainProxy**(self):
return CP3FilterChainProxy(filterInvocationDefinitionSour ce = 
[
("/login.*", ["httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter"]),
("/.*", ["httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter",
"exception_translation_filter",
"auth_processing_filter",
"filter_security_interceptor"])
])

@Object
def httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter(self):
filter = HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter()
filter.sessionStrategy = self.session_strategy()
return filter

@Object
def session_strategy(self):
return CP3SessionStrategy()

@Object
def exception_translation_filter(self):
filter = ExceptionTranslationFilter()
filter.authenticationEntryPoint = self.auth_filter_entry_pt()
filter.accessDeniedHandler = self.accessDeniedHandler()
return filter

@Object
def auth_filter_entry_pt(self):
filter = AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint()
filter.loginFormUrl = "/login"
filter.redirectStrategy = self.redirectStrategy()
return filter

@Object
def accessDeniedHandler(self):
handler = SimpleAccessDeniedHandler()
handler.errorPage = "/accessDenied"
handler.redirectStrategy = self.redirectStrategy()
return handler

@Object
def redirectStrategy(self):
return CP3RedirectStrategy()

@Object
def auth_processing_filter(self):
filter = AuthenticationProcessingFilter()
filter.auth_manager = self.auth_manager()
filter.alwaysReauthenticate = False
return filter

@Object
def auth_manager(self):
auth_manager = AuthenticationManager()
auth_manager.auth_providers = [self.auth_provider()]
return auth_manager

@Object
def auth_provider(self):
provider = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
provider.user_details_service = self.user_details_service()
provider.password_encoder = PlaintextPasswordEncoder()
return provider

@Object
def user_details_service(self):
user_details_service = InMemoryUserDetailsService()
user_details_service.user_dict = {
"alice": ("alicespassword",["ROLE_CUSTOMER"], True),
"bob": ("bobspassword", ["ROLE_MGR"], True),
"carol": ("carolspassword", ["ROLE_SUPERVISOR"], True)
}
return user_details_service


@Object
def filter_security_interceptor(self):
filter = FilterSecurityInterceptor()
filter.auth_manager = self.auth_manager()
filter.access_decision_mgr = self.access_decision_mgr()
filter.sessionStrategy = self.session_strategy()
filter.obj_def_source = [
("/.*", ["ROLE_CUSTOMER", "ROLE_MGR", "ROLE_SUPERVISOR"])
]
return filter

@Object
def access_decision_mgr(self):
access_decision_mgr = AffirmativeBased()
access_decision_mgr.allow_if_all_abstain = False
access_decision_mgr.access_decision_voters = [RoleVoter()]
return access_decision_mgr
```

```
import cherrypy

from springpython.security import *
from springpython.security.providers import *
from springpython.security.context import *

class SpringBankView(object):

def __init__(self):
self.filter = None
self.auth_provider = None
self.http_context_filter = None

@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
return """
Welcome to SpringBank!
<p>
<p>
<a href="logout">Logout</a href>
"""

@cherrypy.expose
def login(self, from_page="/", login="", password="", error_msg=""):
if login != "" and password != "":
try:
self.attempt_auth(login, password)
raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect(from_page)
except AuthenticationException, e:
raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect(
"?login=%s&error_msg=Username/password failure"
% login)

return """
%s<p>
<form method="POST" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Login:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="login"
value="%s"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="from_page" value="%s"/><br/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
""" % (error_msg, login, from_page)

def attempt_auth(self, username, password):
token = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password)
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = \
self.auth_provider.authenticate(token)
self.http_context_filter.saveContext()

@cherrypy.expose
def logout(self):
self.filter.logout()
self.http_context_filter.saveContext()
raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("/")
```

The full source code is found in the url:
https://www.packtpub.com/sites/defau.../0660_Code.zip

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `filterChainProxy` is not a CherryPy thing, it is defined in your second code block, and apparently it should be then assigned to `tools.filterChainProxy`, but for some reason it's not.